# org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage available on Linux, but not on the Mac?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Most esteemed host of Eclipse magi ..

I am trying to create an instance of the org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage class. I have one project where I do this, and it will compile & run on Linux, but not on a Mac. Both machines are running the Helios edition of Eclipse with the PDE, both were downloaded with the last week.

The bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui is available on the Mac, but for some reason the Mac will not  compile the phrase

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage;
```

Saying "The import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage cannot be resolved". The MANIFEST.MF is a simple one ..

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: RcpTest0
Bundle-SymbolicName: rcpTest0; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: rcptest0.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Your clues & boos are all most welcome.

Comment: Do you try to run your project in your IDE on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! The answer was that I had current versions of the JDT checked out in other projects in the workspace. They were being picked in preference over the JARs. Now to understand how I can get the PDE and JDT source bundles downloaded & installed.

Comment: The source bundles for the PDE and JDT are included with the 'SDK' release of Eclipse, and nowhere else, apparently.